# How I can remove the dot when I want to edit a react compound component with the jscodeshift library?

Tags: reactjs, jscodeshift

I have a small project and I want to pass from `<ThemeContext.Provider />` to `<ThemeProvider />`. but when I tried I got `<ThemeProvider. />` (with an **extra dot!!!**)

Here is an example: https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/e06688772514aefc6e776a6a0031dbf5/eb8bf6546886b2ea2f2bf5bf425ebe024f49d217

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find all `JSXMemberExpression` which effectively corresponds to having `Foo.Bar` in opening or closing element `JSXBoundaryElement` name. Filter those accessing `ThemeContext`. And then replace them with identifier

```
source
    .find(j.JSXMemberExpression)
    .filter((path) => path.value.object.name === "ThemeContext")
    .forEach((path) => {
      j(path).replaceWith(j.identifier("ThemeProvider"));
    });
```